# activemq where is the destinations tag?

Tags: activemq-classic

I am reading this book "Activemq In Action". In the section (appendix D) where they are trying to configure the activemq, it is mentioned that

```
<destinations>
<topic name="topic1" physicalName="jms.topic1"/>
</destinations?
```

But I can't locate any tags containing "destinations" in the file activemq.xml. I tried both the versions 5.4.3 (as the version 5.2.0 used in the book could not be downloaded) and the latest version 5.9.0. None have any section containing destinations tag. Now if I want to run the examples in the book (like the chat application), how can I configure the activemq?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

an ActiveMQ server will create any topic or queue that receives a message if it doesn't exist already. You dont need to create them previously, just run the server, send the message and that's all.

I haven't read the book but I think you don't need to find that file (i couldn't find it in my server either) in order to run any sample app pointing to an ActiveMQ server.